# HTML title(?) for a Div (Picture included)

Tags: html, css

(First post on Stackoverflow, if there is anything im missing feel free to let me know)

[What I am trying to accomplish, marked in Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv4xL.png)

I've been working with a few things, but can't figure it out. I don't know where to look to find if that type of styling is it's own thing or is it some sort of manipulation of code?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Forms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        div.a{
            border: 2px solid black;

        }
        div.border{
            border: 10px solid black;
            padding:10px;
        }
        div.color{
            border:15px solid #46516C;
            pading: 4px;
        }

        p.a{
            padding-top: -25px;
        }



    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="color">
    <div class="border">
    <div class="a">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
    <p class="a">Card Ownership</p>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name = "ownership" value="Personal" checked>
        Personal<br>
            </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name = "ownership" value="Buisness">
        Buisness<br>
        </label>
    </form>
    </div>


    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="conformation" checked> I confirm that this purchase has been authorized.
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [HTML Fieldset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp)

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Card Ownership:</legend>
    Name: <input type="text"><br> Email: <input type="text"><br> Date of birth: <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! I had a hunch it wasn't messing around with padding or any of those things.

Comment: well, just try putting it to your code and then fix issues.